# trying to apply custome color to div but nothing is happening

Tags: tailwind-css

Here is my folder structure:

```css
src/assets/tailwind.css:

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

```js
src/main.js:

import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import './assets/tailwind.css';

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(router);

app.mount('#app');
```

```js
../tailwind.config.js:

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: ['./index.html','./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
    theme: {
        extend: {
            colors:{
                "weather-primary":'#00668A',
                'weather-secondary':'#004E71',
            },
        },
        container:{
            padding:'2rem',
            center:true,
        },
        screens:{
            'sm':'640px',
            'md':'768px',
        }
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```

```html
/src/App.vue:

<template>
    <div class="flex flex-col max-h-screen bg-weather-primary">
        <site-navigation/>
        <RouterView/>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
    import {RouterView} from 'vue-router';
    import siteNavigation from './components/siteNavigation.vue';
</script>
```

I am trying to apply custom colors to a `div` using classes from my TailwindCSS file, but nothing is happening. What is the issue?

--------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: can you add the actual class you have added to the div. It is missing from your code.

Comment: sorry, I delete it from class for testing

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the way you are extending colors. I suspect that div doesn't have a size right now or is the size of your siteNavigation and thus being overridden by its bg color. I don't have the time to build the vue project, but I would suggest inspecting your html and seeing the size of that div. Alternatively, you could change the class `max-h-screen` to `h-screen` and see.

Comment: Let me know if its working now. If not, check if a regular class like `bg-black` works. Then we can look at the tailwind config inside of vue but the actual way you are extending colors is just fine.

Comment: it seems like every thing inside the div class are not working

Comment: I've been wacthing videos about using tailwind css to create a web page and I follow the steps exactly it does but it failed

Comment: A few questions. 1. Is anything rendering on the screen like your siteNavigation component? 2. Did you change max-h-screen to h-screen? Add w-screen also to check and then change bg-weather-primary to 'bg-black'? Is a background color appearing? 3. Add a style attribute tag to add a background color and check if its working. 4. Inspect the html (and post it) so we can see what is actually rendering.

Comment: I add the text to siteNavigation components,it has text in it and i have changed max-h-screen to h-screen but now i am going to try the w-screen. for 3, the style attribute tags do work, i add bacground color : red; width:300px,height:300px; everything work just it expect to do

Comment: now i am runing into a issue it says Failed to load PostCSS config: Failed to load PostCSS config (searchPath: C:/Users/busho/Desktop/vue-design/vue-project): [Error] Loading PostCSS Plugin failed: Cannot find module 'tailwindcss' because I put some of code from internet

Comment: Perfect. We are getting somewhere. Tailwinds relies on post css, so you need to install it and you need a postcss.config.js file. Did you look through the docs for vue? https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vue-3-vite.  What build tool are you using?

Comment: it never happend before i don't know where gose wrong

Comment: i have postcss.config.js here is the code module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}

Comment: vue3 tailwind autoprefixer

Comment: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite#vue. Make sure you've installed all these dependencies and have all these files.

Comment: i need to start over again, Many thanks

Comment: thanks a lot, I follow the steps from the documents that you give me, everything works